# Update an Excel sheet in real time using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is there a way to update a spreadsheet in real time while it is open in Excel? I have a workbook called Example.xlsx which is open in Excel and I have the following python code which tries to update cell B1 with the string 'ID':

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet']
sheet['B1'] = 'ID'

wb.save('Example.xlsx')
```

On running the script I get this error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Example.xlsx'`

I know its because the file is currently open in Excel, but was wondering if there is another way or module I can use to update a sheet while its open.

Comment: You can try using [Pyvot](https://pypi.org/project/Pyvot/)

Comment: If you don't need to edit it in Excel, you can open it as read-only. Then you can write to it from python while it's opened

Comment: @zipa Sure let me look into it

Comment: @BalázsKovacsics But I wont be able save anything if I open it as read-only. I have tried that and still gives the same 'Permission denied' error.

Comment: I didn't try it myself with a proper xls, but I ran into a similar problem with csv files. If it's opened in Excel as read-only, python can open the file for write, and edit it. Problem is, that Excel can only refresh cell data without closing and reopening a file if it comes from an external connection (at least according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/353789/how-can-i-refresh-a-document-i-have-open-in-excel-in-read-only-mode)). So while it worked with an imported csv, I'm not sure it would work here.

Comment: @BalázsKovacsics Cool seems external connecting might work, I'll set it up and test.

Comment: @BalázsKovacsics xlwings seems to solve the issue real easy, I've posted the solution

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have actually figured this out and its quite simple using xlwings. The following code opens an existing Excel file called Example.xlsx and updates it in real time, in this case puts in the value 45 in cell B2 instantly soon as you run the script.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Example.xlsx')
sht1 = wb.sheets['Sheet']
sht1.range('B2').value = 45
```

Comment: Just a word on why this is working. `xlwings` uses the [COM interface](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html#dependencies) in the background (on Windows). So it supports real time updating. Other tools, e.g. openpyxl as mentioned below use a different approach. They extract the xlsx file, which is a zip file, and import the data into an empty spreadsheet.

Answer (score 6):

You've already worked out why you can't use `openpyxl` to write to the `.xlsx` file: it's locked while Excel has it open. You can't write to it directly, but you can use `win32com` to communicate with the copy of Excel that is running via its COM interface.

You can download `win32com` from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32 .

Use it like this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb=xlApp.Workbooks.Item("MyExcelFile.xlsx")
ws=wb.Sheets("MyWorksheetName")
```

At this point, `ws` is a reference to a worksheet object that you can change. The objects you get back aren't Python objects but a thin Python wrapper around VBA objects that obey their own conventions, not Python's.

There is some useful if rather old Python-oriented documentation here: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html

There is full documentation for the object model here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx but bear in mind that it is addressed to VBA programmers.

Comment: Thanks., I actually just found out the xlwings module allows to do that quite simply.

Comment: @West Just so you know, `xlwings` is an alternative Python wrapper around exactly the same COM interface. So the Excel objects you get back from it are no harder or easier to use because the behaviour is identical.

Comment: True, understood. I did get this error though when I used your code example and I couldnt figure out why:   `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)`

Comment: *Guessing* That was probably when you tried to open the file.  File path, I suspect. Anyhow, you have a working solution and that is why you posted on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stream real time data into Excel from Python, you can use an RTD function. If you've ever used the Bloomberg add-in use for accessing real time market data in Excel then you'll be familiar with RTD functions.

The easiest way to write an RTD function for Excel in Python is to use PyXLL. You can read how to do it in the docs here: https://www.pyxll.com/docs/userguide/rtd.html

There's also a blog post showing how to stream live tweets into Excel using Python here: https://www.pyxll.com/blog/a-real-time-twitter-feed-in-excel/

If you wanted to write an RTD server to run outside of Excel you have to register it as a COM server. The pywin32 package includes an example that shows how to do that, however it only works for Excel prior to 2007. For 2007 and later versions you will need this code https://github.com/pyxll/exceltypes to make that example work (see the modified example from pywin32 in exceltypes/demos in that repo).

Comment: check this link out for a video walkthru: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNRuB7QlcJo

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an Excel file that's being used by another application because the file format does not support concurrent access.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the file format. It's the fact that the Excel *program* acquires a lock (at the operating system level) that prevents other applications from writing to the same file. Some other application (such as the HxD hex editor) can happily open an Excel file without locking it.

Comment: Having read the specifciation I can assure you that it has everything to do with the file format. On MacOS Excel does not bother with locks.

Comment: What are you trying to illustrate by the MacOS statement? If Excel doesn't lock the file on the Mac but does on Windows, then that would be every evidence that the file format does **not** matter, since it's the same format on both platforms, yet different behavior. Unless you mean something else by "lock". Can a 2nd program open *and write to* a file that is *already* open in Excel on a Mac? If so, again that is evidence *against* the file format having any bearing at all here (and indeed flatly contradicts your answer).

Comment: On Windows Excel acquires an exclusive lock on the file, but this is not the case on the other major OS for which Excel is available. The specification mandates zip files as the package format and these are not editable inplace, this precludes concurrent editing. But, hey, you know better so I'm looking forward to your library.

Comment: So are you saying that a 2nd program on a Mac *cannot* edit a file open by Excel?