# Save Excel operation is not properly done

Tags: python, robotframework, openpyxl

I am using custom Excel library which is based on openpyxl module

Following are the keywords:

```
def open_excel(self, file):
    self.filename = file
    self.wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.filename)

def write_data_by_coordinates(self,sheetname,row_value, column_value,varValue):
     self.sheet = self.wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)
    self.row = int(row_value)
    self.column = int(column_value)
    self.varValue = varValue
    self.sheet.cell(row=self.row, column=self.column).value = self.varValue    

def save_excel(self, file):
    self.file = file
    self.wb.save(self.file)
```

Using Robot Framework, I’m trying to write the values in excel  and save it as below:

```
Write Data in Excel
     Open Excel      D:\\TestExcel.xlsx
     Write Data By Coordinates    Sheet1    1    1   Test1
     Write Data By Coordinates    Sheet1    1    2   Test2
     Save Excel     D:\\TestExcel.xlsx
```

After execution, I had opened the excel and verified it,the values are updated in excel.
When I tried to close the excel , it shows pop up as “Do you want to Save”?

**Why is this pop-up shown when I did not edit/modify any value in excel sheet?
Is it not saved properly during execution by the keyword “Save excel” keyword?**

I had even tried by adding the below line to the Save excel method in Custom library as

```
 self.wb.close()
```

But still it shows the “Do you want to Save?” popup, when I open and close the excel sheet after test case execution.
Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: i use this it's can save https://github.com/sidarakeo/Robot-Framework-XLSX-Support/blob/master/robotframework_library_xlsx_alpha.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219317/how-to-watch-excel-file-change-while-openpyxl-makes-changes

Comment: As mentioned there, I don't think that is possible with openpyxl. It just opens the file and reads the data. You might be overwriting it when saving. Could you try without the file being open? If you want to monitor live changes you might have to use the COM interface https://stackoverflow.com/a/18595248/7919597

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50413929/7919597

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411346/update-an-excel-sheet-in-real-time-using-python#comment107893060_50421760

Comment: _"Why is this pop-up shown when I did not edit/modify any value in excel sheet?"_ - that's just how excel works. It thinks something changed -- maybe a column width or a row height just due to the fact you opened it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. It's asking why a particular third-party program behaves the way it does.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Intention of asking that question is just to explain the scenario.Since there is a some problem with "Save Excel" keyword, it might have also be the reason for such behavior.

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem with the "Save Excel" keyword? You've proved the data is saved by opening the file in excel. If the data wasn't saved, you wouldn't be able to see it in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just that the excel programme see changes it did not make and thus treats it like you did them at this time of its opening.
You could test this by making an excel file that has never been opened on your PC. Edit with the code and then open with excel.